# sbyte and if operator

Tags: c#, .net

Why the first statement is allowed but not the second in the below sample code?

```
sbyte test1 = true ? 1 : -1;             // Allowed
sbyte test2 = "a".Equals("b") ? 1 : -1;  // Not allowed
```

I checked that all `.Equals(..)` overloads for `string` return a `bool`.

Comment: It might be something to do with the fact that the compiler can optimize the first one to `sbyte test1 = 1;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first statement includes a constant expression that can be evaluated at a compile-time. It's equivalent to this:

```
sbyte test1 = 1;
```

Technically, this is an assignment of an `int` literal (`1`) to an `sbyte` variable. But the compiler is smart enough to figure out that the value is small enough to fit into an `sbyte` range and allows an implicit conversion, i.e. you don't need to cast it to int.

The second statement includes a method call and those are only evaluated at runtime. In other words, the compiler isn't smart enough to simplify an expression. The only thing it knows is that this impression returns an unknown `int` value and those should be converted explicitly. For example, like this:

```
sbyte test2 = (sbyte) ("a".Equals("b") ? 1 : -1);
```

All of this is explained in the C# specification. See, [Implicit constant expression conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#implicit-constant-expression-conversions):

> A constant_expression ([Constant expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#constant-expressions)) of type int can be converted to type sbyte, byte, short, ushort, uint, or ulong, provided the value of the constant_expression is within the range of the destination type.